# django-datatable-view==0.9.0 Django 3.1.3: ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist'

Tags: django

I am using the latest package django-datatable-view 0.9.0 in django 3.1.3 (upgrading from django 1.8.6)

When a I run manage.py run server I get the following error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datatableview/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datatables import Datatable, ValuesDatatable, LegacyDatatable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datatableview/datatables.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist'
```

Upgrading the package is not an option as I am already using the latest package. What can I do to fix the error? Thank you for your help

Comment: They have an active [issue #244](https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view/issues/244)

Comment: Thank you Arakkal Abu

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Arakkal Abu for pointing me in the right direction. The library update is not ready yet. Following their amends I have replaced:

```
from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist
```

with

```
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist
```

in the following files:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datatableview/datatables.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datatableview/columns.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datatableview/utils.py
```

and it works.